# How to output parameter value only when there are the specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<td ng-click = 'membermodal(item)'>{{item.zipcode1}}</td>

-

<td ng-click = 'membermodal(item)'>{{item.zipcode2}}</td>
```

I want to be output `zipCode1-zipCode2` when there is a `zipCode1`.

When there is not a `zipCode1` it should not print `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple conditional statement in place of the `-`:

```
{{ item.zipcode1 != "undefined" ? "-" : "" }}
```

See the following example for usage. Try commenting out the `zipcode1` to see it in action.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Module", function() {
  this.zipcode1 = "try commenting this line out"
  this.zipcode2 = "hello";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Module as item">
  {{ item.zipcode1 }}
  {{ item.zipcode1 != undefined ? "-" : "" }}
  {{ item.zipcode2 }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-show

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.address = [
        {zipCode1 : 12345, zipCode2 : 12345},
        {zipCode1 : 34567, zipCode2 : 23456},
        {zipCode1 : 12345}      
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="addy in address">
       <li>{{addy.zipCode1}}<span ng-show="addy.zipCode2">-{{addy.zipCode2}}</span></li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

or you can use a method

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.address = [
        {zipCode1 : 12345, zipCode2 : 12345},
        {zipCode1 : 34567, zipCode2 : 23456},
        {zipCode1 : 12345}      
    ];
    $scope.zipFmt = function (addy) {
        return addy.zipCode1 + (addy.zipCode2 ? "-" + addy.zipCode2 : "");
     };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="addy in address">
       <li>{{zipFmt(addy)}}  
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, why didn't I think of `ng-show`! That's neater.